# Run SKActions sequence with different nodes

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sequence, skaction

I know that I can create an SKAction.sequence which will run the actions of one node one by one. But how can I do that if I want to do a sequence with different nodes. I'd like to do something like that:

1. Run action from node A
2. wait 2 seconds
3. Run action from node B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @godel9 Could you show me some example code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both nodes are uniquely named and are children of the same node, you can use `runAction:onChildWithName:`, as follows:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:
    @[[SKAction runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f) duration:1.0f]
          onChildWithName:@"NODEA"],
      [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0f],
      [SKAction runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f) duration:1.0f]
          onChildWithName:@"NODEB"]]];

[parent runAction:action];
```

More generally, you can use `runBlock:` to do pretty much anything as a step in an SKAction sequence:

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction sequence:
    @[[SKAction runBlock:^{
          [nodeA runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f) duration:1.0f]];
      }],
      [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0f],
      [SKAction runBlock:^{
          [nodeB runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f) duration:1.0f]];
      }]]];

[parent runAction:action];
```

Comment: Note that `runBlock:` and `runAction:onChildWithName:` both run with an "instantaneous duration" according to the docs, so this sequence would run everything at once if you didn't have the `waitForDuration:` action in there.