# Sequence Action With EnumerateChildNodeWithName

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, fade, alpha

I want two different types of nodes to fade there alpha to 0 one after the other (with a sequence). However to find the nodes to fade, I'm using EnumerateChildNodeWithName and there is two of them, so I'm unable (I think) to use a sequence because I would have to use the sequence outside the EnumerateChildNodeWithName (because there is two of them) and at that point, I lose control of the nodes.

Not sure if this makes sense, but here is my code (this fades both types of nodes are the same time):

```
    nodeMovingPlatform1.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x + nodeMovingPlatform1.position.x > self.frame.size.width/2 + node.frame.size.width/2 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            if node.name == "landscapeTrigger" {
                node.name = "landscape"
                node.runAction(actionFadeAlphaTo0_3)
            }

        }
    }

    nodeMovingPlatform2.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x + nodeMovingPlatform2.position.x > self.frame.size.width/2 + node.frame.size.width/2 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            if node.name == "landscapeTrigger" {
                node.name = "landscape"
                node.runAction(actionFadeAlphaTo0_3)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this would be to make use of `SKAction Sequences`, it only runs the second action once the first action is completed.

**From the Apple Documentation**

> A sequence is a set of actions that run consecutively. When a node
>   runs a sequence, the actions are triggered in consecutive order. When
>   one action completes, the next action starts immediately. When the
>   last action in the sequence completes, the sequence action also
>   completes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is my problem, I can't make a sequence because I have no way of calling both types of nodes because they are children to two different parents.

Comment: Take a look at this, this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823428/run-skactions-sequence-with-different-nodes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the link you have provided is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!