# Run SCNActions sequence with different nodes in SceneKit

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, sequences, scnnode

I know how to create a sequence of **SCNActions** in a single node, one by one, in **SceneKit**. But I would like to know, how can I make a sequence of **SCNActions** with different nodes?
For example

- Move forward node A
- Move forward node B
- Wait 1 second
- Move backward node A

> I found an example with **SpriteKit** but I can not use it, this...
>   [Run SKActions sequence with different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823428/run-skactions-sequence-with-different-nodes)

The code of a sequence is as follows

```
var sequence = [SCNAction] ()
let force = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
let move = SCNAction.move(by: force!, duration: 1.5)
squence.append(move)
let actions = SCNAction.sequence(squence)
nodeSelected?.runAction(actions)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `customAction`.

```
let actionA = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1.5) { (node, elapsedTime) in
    nodeA.position.z -= 1.0
}

let actionB = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1.5) { (node, elapsedTime) in
    nodeB.position.z -= 1.0
}

let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([actionA,actionB])
anyNode.runAction(sequence)
```

Running action with any node will first move nodeA then nodeB.

Comment: Oh thanks for your help, Your answer helped me a lot